# firebase messaging from minSdkVersion error on android with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-android

When I debug on android I get the error regarding minSdkVersion.
I tried adding:

```
android {│
 defaultConfig {
 minSdkVersion 19 
} 
}
```

in the build.gradle file but it didn't work. Also I added:

```
flutter.minSdkVersion = 21
flutter.targetSdkVersion = 30
flutter.compileSdkVersion = 30
```

in the local.properties file but that also didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
  minSdkVersion 21
  multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
...

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Would you mind adding some rationale on why are those changes needed? Thank you!